# Show error to user in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Basically what I have is a datatable that is bound to a DataGridView. What I want to happen is to show a error type tooltip in each of the cells in the datagrid if some exception is true.

I have been able to get the red error alert to show in the cells using CellValidating. The problem is that the user would have to click on a cell and then take that cell out of focus for the alert to become visible.

I also tried using ColumnChanging on the datatable to set the RowError but that didn't work at all. Here is some sample code that I had tried.

`importGrid` is my `DataGridView`,
`csvData` is my `DataTable`

```
private void importGrid_CellValidating(object sender, 
                                       DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
  this.importGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText ="Drive Letter in use";
}

private void csvData_ColumnChanging(object sender, 
                                    System.Data.DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
   e.Row.RowError = "test error";
   e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column, "test error 2");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you loop over all `Rows` and `Cells` after the binding, test the condition and set the `ErrorText`?

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DGV.Rows)
foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) 
    if (yourCondition) cell.ErrorText = yourErrorText;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two events you might find useful. [`RowErrorTextNeeded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowerrortextneeded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`CellErrorTextNeeded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellerrortextneeded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Here is an example from one of my projects using `RowErrorTextNeeded`. This event is fired by the `DataGridView` when the row becomes visible, or anything has changed.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowErrorTextNeeded( object sender, DataGridViewRowErrorTextNeededEventArgs e )
{
    DataGridView dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
    if( dataGridView != null )
    {
        DataRowView view = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        if( view != null )
        {
            if( view.Row[invColorColumn] == DBNull.Value )
                e.ErrorText = "Color code is missing from part database.";
            else if( view.Row[invThickColumn] == DBNull.Value )
                e.ErrorText = "Thickness is missing from part database.";
            else if( view.Row[invWidthColumn] == DBNull.Value )
                e.ErrorText = "Width is missing from part database.";
            else if( view.Row[invHeightColumn] == DBNull.Value )
                e.ErrorText = "Height is missing from part database.";
            else 
                e.ErrorText = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```